# How do I include a file in a helm config map

Tags: helm

I have a helm deployment that includes a several configmaps.
I would like to add a few rather large files to it and I thought I coud put them in a an external directory

```
my-app/values.yaml
my-app/conf/my-large-file1.conf
my-app/conf/my-large-file2.conf
my-app/templates/configmaps.yaml
```

I thought I could use include but this did not work

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: example1
data:
  index.html: {{ include "/conf/my-large-file1.conf" . }}
```

Error:

```
template: my-app/templates/configmaps.yaml:23:17: executing "my-app/templates/configmaps.yaml" at <include "/conf/my-large-file1.conf" .>: error calling include: template: no template "/conf/my-large-file1.conf" associated with tem\
    plate "gotpl"
```

I then tried different things with  `{{ $.Files.Get "conf/my-large-file1.conf" }}` but got weird scoping errors.

So my hope is that someone can tell me how to do it correctly

```
$ helm version
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.11.1+6.el8", GitCommit:"66bfc44f827aea6eb8e001150914170ac0d49e2d", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.18.9"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up solving it

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: app-cm
data:
  app.properties: |-
    {{- tpl ($.Files.Get "conf/app.properties.tmpl") . | nindent 4 }}

  app-users.properties: |-
    {{- tpl ($.Files.Get "conf/app-users.properties.tmpl") . | nindent 4 }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `Files.Glob` , `Files.AsConfig` and with indentation. Similar pattern works for me ->

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: example1
data:
{{ (.Files.Glob "conf/my-large-file1.conf").AsConfig | indent 2 }}
```

`Files.Glob` - [reference](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/#glob-patterns)

`AsConfig` - [reference](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/builtin_objects/#:%7E:text=Files.AsConfig%20is%20a%20function%20that%20returns%20file%20bodies%20as%20a%20YAML%20map.).